# Binary Image data in Featherlight Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-gallery, featherlight.js

Using binary image data in [featherlight plugin](http://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/) works just fine using the *data-featherlight="image"* parameter. Using binary image data in a [featherlight gallery](http://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/gallery.html) shows the images correctly, but don't link them together to a gallery.

Here a simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geraldo/kmfLLdgq/) using the basic featherlight syntax like this:

```
<a href="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7" data-featherlight="image">
  <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that binary image data doesn't have to do anything with the problem of not linking images together to a Featherlight Gallery.

I add the images dynamically and that seems to happen after binding Featherligth. So I had to manually bind it like that and everything works ok:

```
$(".gallery").featherlightGallery();
```